# Python requests: правильные параметры post запроса для доступа ко внутренней странице сайта (XHR)

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests, xhr

Есть сайт. Нужно получить данные из таблицы, расположенной глубоко внутри (в админ-панели). По прямому URL можно добраться только до редактирования товарной карточки. Дальше идут вкладки, которые не имеют отдельных URL. Я так понимаю, что все это работает на JS.

Насколько смог найти информацию, нужно посылать POST запрос с параметрами/хедером. Но упорно не получается ничего добиться. Если с авторизацией на сайте разобрался, то с этими табами - нет. Не могу понять, нужно ли передавать все данные из `Request Headers` или только какие-то конкретные. Или нужно передать еще и `__RequestVerificationToken` или `Query String Parameters`. Перепробовал разные комбинации и глухо. На подобные запросы приходит стандартная "заглушка" (HTML страница с текстом: Наш персонал был уведомлен об этой ошибке и будет решать вопрос в ближайшее время.). Судя по всему, срабатывает исключение:

> expect-ct: max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"

Вот сюда нужно пробиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Network показывает следующее (токены и пр. сократил):

```
**General**
Request URL: https://www.site.com/Admin/Product/ProductAttributeCombinationList?productId=6883
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: ip:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**
cache-control: private
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 601199dfac5f15f4-ARN
cf-request-id: 06fede7fc6000015f492188000000001
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 13 Dec 2020 18:03:18 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
nel: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=PFNGmVGuxN%2F%2B2V7g6QRyrSR3MzplfxlDuxWIF1vMFhgRXNg0kNtClCuAPjrto4C%2FsvaUB8vZ2xGzwCRl5QRbXJ3kIafMdp1NBoDRepNm"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: Nop.customer=f63da1b3-be41-4bb8-9341-07b5ebcfbcef; expires=Mon, 13-Dec-2021 18:03:15 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

**Request Headers**
:authority: www.site.com
:method: POST
:path: /Admin/Product/ProductAttributeCombinationList?productId=6883
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
content-length: 156
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: przvdom=9***5; przvgl=5***a; przv_new_w=1; __RequestVerificationToken=1***1; przvlng=ru; ASP.NET_SessionId=x***a; _ga=GA1.2.1669959674.1606847171; _fbp=fb.1.1606847171381.1968299613; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjid=4ea5c46e-f0ee-4380-8575-e6436bf33422; NopCommerce.RecentlyViewedProducts=RecentlyViewedProductIds=5819&RecentlyViewedProductIds=3792&RecentlyViewedProductIds=5591; __atuvc=20%7C49%2C25%7C50; __cfduid=d***2; przvusr=7**1; _gid=GA1.2.1659529086.1607861115; przvdistance=361; NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH=A***A; Nop.customer=f***f; przvonline=517
dnt: 1
origin: https://www.site.com
referer: https://www.site.com/Admin/Product/Edit/6883
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

**Query String Parameters**
productId: 6883

**Form Data**
__RequestVerificationToken: 8***0
```

Код, который использую:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.site.com/login'
header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
aut_data = {
     'Email': 'email@site.com',
     'Password': 'R****',
     'RememberMe':'true',
}
# Авторизация
post_request = session.post(url, data=aut_data, headers=header)

# Попытка получить данные из вкладки
link = 'https://www.site.com/Admin/Product/ProductAttributeCombinationList?productId=6883'
table = session.post(link, headers=header)
table.encoding = 'utf-8'
print (table.text)
```

Может кто-нибудь сможет подсобить? Спасибо!

Comment: на какой сайт пытаетесь залогиниться и парсить?

Comment: По идее, то что указано в Form Data нужно передавать через параметр data, например `table = session.post(link, data={'__RequestVerificationToken': '8***0'}, headers=header)`

Comment: @Jack_oS Это интернет-магазин одного нашего клиента. Пытаемся решить небольшую проблему и самое простое/бюджетное решение - это парсер, как ни странно :).

Comment: @insolor К сожалению, что-то тут не то. Я уже пробовал этот вариант - выдает все ту же страницу: https://ibb.co/BjRFxLp

Comment: @OlafGusterson а __RequestVerificationToken берете тот что в сессии в куки записался, или тот что у вас в браузере отобразился? Они скорее всего разные будут. Т.е. по идее нужно после авторизации брать его из кук и передавать в пост запросе.

Comment: @insolor Собрал куки в словарь и вытащил значение токена:
`cookies_dict = [{"domain": key.domain, "name": key.name, "path": key.path, "value": key.value}
                for key in session.cookies]`
`token = cookies_dict[3].get('value')`
Потом передал его в:
`table = session.post(link, data={'__RequestVerificationToken': token}, headers=user_header)`
Но получаю все ту же страницу в ответ, что и прежде. Может я делаю что-то не так?

Comment: Дальше уже без самого сайта трудно что-то предположить. Я бы вот так токен вытаскивал (мало ли, вдруг порядок поменяется): `token = next(key.value for key in session.cookies if key.name == '__RequestVerificationToken')`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Буду искать решение дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительно в запросе кроме заголовков передать еще в `params` словарь `Form Data`

```
reqAnsw = req.post(URL_TEMPLATE, params=data, headers=header)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]